# Trying to save objects in a many-to-many relationship (multiple inheritance)

Tags: django

I'm doing a django app for an educational school, and I have a two classes (RegularSchoolClass and AdhocSchoolClass) that inherit from a SchoolClass (not abstract). I have another class (LessonSchedule) that records the weekly or daily schedule of a class and has a many to many relationship with SchoolClass.

Upon saving of a regularschoolclass, I'm trying to update the relevant lesson schedule (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/db/examples/many_to_many/).

I'm getting the following error - I assume this is because LessonSchedule is a many-to-many relationship with SchoolClass rather than RegularSchoolClass? Is there a way to make it work though (I don't really want to duplicate the same code for both RegularSchoolClass and AdhocSchoolClass)?

```
ValueError: Cannot add "<RegularSchoolClass: Kindergarten One, Dan, Saturday, 9:00AM - 10:45AM>": the value for field "schoolclass" is None
```

models.py

```
class SchoolClass(TimeStampedModel):
    pass

class RegularSchoolClass(SchoolClass):
    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        for l in LessonSchedule.objects.filter(lesson_frequency=self.lesson_frequency, start_date=self.start_date):
            l.schoolclass.add(self)

class AdhocSchoolClass(SchoolClass):
    pass

class LessonSchedule(models.Model):
    school_class = models.ManyToManyField(SchoolClass)
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to add a field school class to your class SchoolClass

```
school_class=models.CharField(max_length=some length)
```